# Setting up Self Hosted Agent on Windows machine : WRITE ERROR: An error occurred: Not configured

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

Trying to set up Self Hosted Azure DevOps Agent on the windows machine.
Pre-requisites are verified and hold good - Windows 10 machine, Powershell 5.1, .NET Framework 4.7. PAT is properly configured, the Agent Administrator role is assigned to the user. When run.cmd is executed, the message appears "the error occurs: Not configured"

When checked the logs under _diag folder, this is a snapshot of the error

```
[2020-04-16 18:47:26Z INFO ConfigurationManager] LoadSettings
[2020-04-16 18:47:26Z INFO ConfigurationStore] IsConfigured()
[2020-04-16 18:47:26Z INFO ConfigurationStore] IsConfigured: False
[2020-04-16 18:47:26Z INFO ConfigurationManager] Is configured: False
[2020-04-16 18:47:26Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: An error occurred: Not configured
[2020-04-16 18:47:26Z ERR  AgentProcess] System.InvalidOperationException: Not configured
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.LoadSettings()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.ExecuteCommand(CommandSettings command)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Program.MainAsync(IHostContext context, String[] args)
```

Appreciate to receive any inputs

Comment: What happens when you run config.cmd?

Comment: This works. I run config.cmd first, it was successful. I then ran run.cmd. I can see the agent online. This resolved the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`config.cmd` must be be ran and complete successfully before running `run.cmd`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the agent was corrupted. the config.cmd was missing entirely. Reinstalling the agent resolved the issue.